# renumber(set column to rank) a column after order by on that column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-update, drizzle

in sql, i want to do something like

```
update table set col = rank(col) order by col
```

how do i do this ?

Purpose :

currently the col has extreme values, like -14000, 23, 4000, 23000 ... they are used in asc, desc sort but when i plot them on a slider, having say 10 positions, each slider position has highly uneven data, so to even it out i wish to renumber the column,

```
-14000 becomes 0
23 becomes 1
4000 becomes 2
```

and so on

Comment: @pilcrow i am using drizzle : http://www.drizzle.org/ ... its a branch of mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used this :

```
update table set col = (select count(*) from (select col from table) as temptable where temptable.col <table.col );
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use two subqueries and the `ROW_NUMBER` function. In cases where you have duplicates in `col`, the ranking will follow [standard competition ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_.28.221224.22_ranking.29).

Sample script:

```sql
SELECT * INTO #TABLE
FROM
(
    select -14000 col
    union all SELECT 23
    union all select 4000
    union all SELECT 23 --sample duplicated data
) Unioned

UPDATE #TABLE
SET col =
(
    SELECT top 1 rowNum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            col
            , row_number() OVER (order by col) - 1 rowNum --starts at 0 rank
        FROM #TABLE
    ) MySubQuery
    WHERE MySubQuery.col = #TABLE.col
)
```

Comment: i am worried about this part of your query : `    select -14000 col
    union all SELECT 23
    union all select 4000
    union all SELECT 23 --sample duplicated data
` my data in the question was just an example, i have 120,000 rows... do i have to list all in there ?

Comment: @Pheonix: Definitely not! I only included the `SELECT INTO` statement in the example to provide a proof of concept. For your real table, you can just use the `UPDATE` statement and replace `#Table` with your real table name. Of course, creating a temp table to test the update first wouldn't be such a bad idea...

Comment: sorry it doesnt works, probably problem is something specific to drizzle :: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Drizzle server version for the right syntax to use near '1 rowNum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sw
            , row_number(' at line 3`

Comment: @Pheonix: Right; this is because `ROW_NUMBER` is not available in MySQL. There are several answers @ SO that translate the `ROW_NUMBER` function to MySQL, so if you can't find the right translation and if someone else doesn't post a MySQL specific solution, I'll try to post an edit later tonight.